# Import Microsoft access to postgresql database in php

Tags: postgresql, ms-access

Please help me to resolve the issue, I am getting the data in MS access(example.mdb) and the database I am using is postgres. I need to import the data of ms access(example.mdb) to postgress database table(table_master) in PHP.

Please share the PHP code and steps so that I can get the help on the same.

Comment: I strongly advise you to search for past questions on this topic. The short answer is that there's no push-button "import my schema and data" tool for MS Access -> PostgreSQL

Comment: It means there is no solution for the same. please help to have link on the same

Comment: What have you tired up until this point?

Answer (score 0):

PHP can connect to both databases using [ODBC](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php). So connect to one DB, import and save data in a PHP array or other object, then export data to other connected DB using append queries.

```
$connection = odbc_connect("Driver= {Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};
Dbq=$mdbFilename", $username, $password);

$connection = odbc_connect("Driver={PostgreSQL};Server=[IP address];Port=5432;
Database=$DataBase;", $username, $password);
```

Alternatively, you can [link external tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722917.aspx) within MS Access, then run an insert append query using the local and linked tables.

For both solutions, you need to install the [PostgreSQL odbc driver](https://odbc.postgresql.org/).